# Would it be possible to authenticate over SSL via a web service (SOAP) and return to the browser via HTTP?

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, soap, ssl

I have been assigned the task of not using SSL over the entire site.  There is nothing on the site that's confidential, but the powers-that-be are required to have some sort of protection due to PCI compliance.  As a compromise, I brought up using authentication over HTTPS (SSL) and allowing the rest of the site to run over HTTP.

Would it be possible to authenticate over HTTPS (SSL), via a web service like SOAP, then return to the browser over HTTP?

I have seen implementations that use SSO with CAS and Active Directory that are sessionless, which permit authentication via HTTPS and leave everything else in HTTP.  I want to accomplish the same thing (auth via SSL only), but without SSO and Active Directory.  I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2, Tomcat 5.5, and IIS 7.5.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Is the intent to have the user provide credentials to an authentication screen/dialog, forward those credentials to an auth service and establish a token (cookie) which will be used for the remainder of the session?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  The user will provide credentials to an authenticator.  The authenticator will set certain variables and set a session (jsessionid), both of which will be used for the remainder of the session.  Is it possible to use a web service in this manner, to authenticate via HTTPS and leave everything else on the site in HTTP?